# Nested grid layout using flexbox and before hack

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can someone explain how this example works?

1. Why is `.content::before` used there?
2. Why if I uncomment the 19th line (`/*   align-items: center; */`) all just broke?

PS: the same code [at codepen](https://codepen.io/dchebakov/pen/mdddxww)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
/*  align-items: center; */
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap; 
 align-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gold;
}

.content::before, .content::after {
  content: '';
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
  order: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.content::after {
  display: none;
}

.content > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0.0033rem;
}

.a {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 2 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 1;
}

.b {
  width: calc(100%  / 3 * 1 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 2;
}

.c {
  width:  calc(100% / 3  * 1 + 0.0033rem); 
  order: 2;
}

.a { background: red;  }
.b { background: green;  }
.c { background: blue; }

.a, .b, .c {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
    <div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `::before` pseudo element

Pseudo elements applied to a flex container are considered to be flex items ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/23#CSS)).

Therefore, the `::before` element is a flex item in the `.content` flex container. If the `::after` pseudo were not set to `display: none`, it too would be a flex item of `.content`.

In short, the `.content` flex container has four items, and the pseudo is set to `order: 2`. So the elements are ordered something like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <css pseudo element></css pseudo element>
    <div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
</div>
```

The pseudo is set to `flex-basis: 100%`.

```
.content::before {
  content: '';
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
  order: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

In a column-direction container (i.e., `.content`), this is equivalent to `height: 100%`.

Since the container is also set to `wrap`, the item with `height: 100%` takes a full column and forces subsequent items to a new column.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: center; */
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gold;
}

.content::before,
.content::after {
  content: '';
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0;
  order: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.content::after {
  display: none;
}

.content>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0.0033rem;
}

.a {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 2 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 1;
}

.b {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 1 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 2;
}

.c {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 1 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 2;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: green;
}

.c {
  background: blue;
}

.a,
.b,
.c {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 120px;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
    <div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The DOM elements are set to `min-height: 120px`...

```
.a, .b, .c {
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

...but they consume all the height in the container because they are also set to `flex-grow: 1`:

```
.content > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

The pseudo column is completely invisible because it is set to `width: 0`.

If, let's say, you added width or content, the column created by the pseudo would become visible:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: center; */
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gold;
}

.content::before,
.content::after {
  content: 'X';
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /* width: 0; */
  order: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.content::after {
  display: none;
}

.content>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0.0033rem;
}

.a {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 2 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 1;
}

.b {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 1 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 2;
}

.c {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 1 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 2;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: green;
}

.c {
  background: blue;
}

.a,
.b,
.c {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 120px;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
    <div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### `align-items: center`

The layout, as described above, with `align-items: center` disabled on the primary flex container (`.container`), allows items `.b` & `.c` to wrap because the `::before` pseudo item occupies all space in a previous column with `flex-basis: 100%`. The viewport sets the height limitation and break point for the wrap.

When you enable `align-items: center`, the container (`.content`) is centered vertically through the distribution of free space. There is no height limitation anymore. There is no break point telling items to wrap. So all items (including the pseudo) remain in a single column.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;  /* enabled */
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  background-color: gold;
}

.content::before,
.content::after {
  content: 'X';
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /* width: 0; */
  order: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.content::after {
  display: none;
}

.content>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-height: 0.0033rem;
}

.a {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 2 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 1;
}

.b {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 1 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 2;
}

.c {
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 1 + 0.0033rem);
  order: 2;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: green;
}

.c {
  background: blue;
}

.a,
.b,
.c {
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 120px;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 1rem/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="a">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
    <div class="b">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="c">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
  </div>
</div>
```